# Wordpress comment_form( ) won't accept my arguments

Tags: wordpress, comments

I'm trying to diligently follow what the codex says about modifying the appearance of the comments form (located [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form)) but I can't get it to work. The default comments form appears despite my array of arguments that should change it.

In the template I have: `comments_template('mycomments.php');`

Then...

```
    <?php
    //inside my mycomments.php file

$comment_args = array (
    'fields' => array('author', 'email'),
    'must_log_in' => true,
    'title_reply' => 'Review this product',
    'label_submit' => 'Submit',
);
comment_form($comment_args, $post->ID); ?>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There's no error. I just get the default comment form: "Leave a reply..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There was nothing wrong with my arguments. Instead... I needed a `/` infront of the relative link to my customized comments template:

`comments_template('/mycomments.php');`

Moral of the story: If you're having trouble getting the template to work (at all), make sure you're actually loading the right template file!